# Does nodejs http client has a limit concurrency connection

Tags: node.js

When I request too much resources of one site, some request will occurs NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. How to fix?

`http.request(options, callback)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely a limitation of the server you're connecting to and not Node.js. This is usually implemented to keep people from opening too many connections (much like you're trying to do. :)

Comment: How to increase it?  I face the same issue too.

Comment: @murvinlai, As Brandon pointed out, you can't.  This has nothing to do with your code, and with the server you're connecting to.